# Disable whole UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

My app needs to save an image to disk. I do this in a separate thread, so the UI is still responsive, BUT, I do not want the user to add a new image until the first one is saved (about 1 second.)

At the moment, I'm disabling the 'take another picture' button and greying it out, but I'm wondering if there is a method that will disable the whole view, greying out the buttons and darkening the background, like what happens when a UIActionSheet is presented.

I've looked through the UIView docs and don't see anything like this, but it seems like such a useful pattern that is frequently used by Apple that I figured I'd ask, just in case there was such a thing.

Obviously I could do it manually, but why reinvent the wheel if its already part of the API.

TIA: John

Answer (score 35, accepted):

set whatever view (main view, subview, etc.) you want to appear disabled to

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

and also

```
view.alpha = 0.3f
```

and maybe even

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]
```

to boot.  These last two can be animated, b.t.w.

Comment: Gosh, it was difficult to decide which answer was right... Bourne's method was more like what I was originally thinking, but this method is so easy and look 'right' to me. Wish I could mark both as correct. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 5):

Present another view with the shadow and the gradient etcetera over this view thus giving it an effect of graying out with shadows. You may even create an image if you know your photoshop. Just show that image on a UIImageView over this view to be blocked. Give the image some nice translucency, shadows etc etc